# How to set up Apache Thrift with Eclipse && MinGW in Windows?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, thrift

I need to configure Thrift for Eclipse project with MinGW compiler. I googled for it. I couldn't find proper instructions to do that? Can somebody suggest any suitable way or proper link to do that?

Comment: Why do you "need" to do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several partial answers to this.

1. The Windows build is made by means of MinGW cross compiler on a Linux machine.
2. Since (at least) 0.9.2 it is no longer necessary to use MinGW to build the Thrift compiler on a Windows machine.<sup>1)</sup> Aside from the fact, that you don't need to do that at all, because a precompiled EXE is available on the download pages, there is a nice Visual Studio project to build the Windows Thrift compiler EXE. The project has only two dependencies: Bison and Lexx/Yacc, which are both available elsewhere as precompiled Setups as well.
3. In either case MinGW is only used to build the compiler. If you want to build the libraries with MinGW, I'm not sure if that even works. This way of doing things is not implemented or supported, simply because nobody needs it.

Which brings us back to the question, why you think you "need" it this way.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>To my knowledge, numerous severe problems exist with the autotools and all the stuff needed to build Thrift under MinGW on a Windows machine. You will have to patch things, build some from source, spend a lot of time and do some strange things with your file system to make it work. At least that was the case when I stopped using MinGW to build Thrift about two years ago. And even if you get it to work, you still only get the compiler (which you could easily download in a fraction of that time), not the libraries.</sub>

Comment: unfortunately for me, I DO need to use mingw... one question for you would be... when the thrift instructions for windows compilation say `./bootstrap.sh` I am assuming they mean using msys?

Comment: @Erik: Try it. The event whwn I finally stopped using it was that I ran into an dependency issue with newer MinGW versions on Windows. I don't recall the facts, but there was also some known bug at that time in MinGW which essentielly prevented some of the build steps from running through successfully. I can only wish you good luck. PS: msys yes.

Comment: thanks.. I am new to MinGW and they never explain how to run the scripts anywhere... on the downside.. it looks like the people who packaged up these MINGW compilers never bothered to include MSYS.... I will have to install a version compatible with the GCC I am looking at and cross my fingers

Comment: I ended up not trying to compile thrift.. and instead will attempt to simply the problem by using boost sockets to get what I need.. fingers crossed and thanks for the insights